# How to update database using PHP variables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

```
$Createdby=$_SESSION['adminlog'];
$total =$_POST['total'];
$due =$_POST['due'];
$date =$_POST['issedate'];
$invoiceno =$_POST['invno'];
$CmpnyName =$_POST['CmpnyName'];
$itemdetails =$_POST['item_details'];
$itemname =$_POST['itemname'];
$amtpaid =$_POST['paid'];



$query  = "UPDATE billdata SET Total='$total' Due='$due' WHERE InvoiceNo=$invoiceno";

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

This is the code I am using to get HTML values to variable and update particular invoice number with new data.

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: What is going wrong ? 
You should first connect to your database using mysql_connect();
Do not forget to check for SQL injection with mysql_real_escape_string() in your case.

Comment: add thing done db connected ,select db n bla bla with this same method i used save (insert) details to table so now m trying to renew (update) selected bill but this method not working

Comment: Your code is a schoolbook example of `sql injection` vulnerable code. Swap from the **deprecated** and unsafe `mysql_*` API to either `mysqli` or `PDO`, and use `prepared statements` or at the least escape/validate the input data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, never use the **deprecated** `mysql_*` API.
Switch to either `PDO` or `mysqli`, both have `prepared statements`, which would make your code a tad bit more safe when it comes to [`SQL-Injections`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (which your code is very open for).

When a query fails, the `mysql_error()` global function will return the latest mysql error.
The easiest way to get information about a failing query is by adding `or die(mysql_error());` after the query execution.
Example with your code:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

This will report your error and stop execute the script.

Your sql code is slightly wrong (as RST mentions), you are missing a comma between the values you are trying to set.

---

Using `mysqli` and `prepared statements`, your code could look something like:

```
// Using the mysqli object oriented style.
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');

// Prepare the statement.
$statement = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE billdata SET Total=?, Due=? WHERE InvoiceNo=?');
// The question marks is placeholders for the input that will be added in a while.

// Bind your parameters (ssi tells mysqli what type of params it is, s = string, i = int).
$statement->bind_param('ssi', $total, $due, $invoceno);
// Execute the statement.
$statement->execute();

// Cleanup.
$statement->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: thanks Jite can i know deference between mysql & mysqli ? 
i learnt about php my admin ( localhost ) using xammp server ! is it this mysqli is  supporting to xammp server ?

Comment: I think that most standard php installation packages includes the mysqli extension, it should be enabled by default. `mysqli` stands for Mysql Improved. It includes stuff like prepared statements (which does not exist in the old api). Its still using the `mysql` database and the same queries can be used, its even possible to convert old `mysql_*` code to `mysqli` using its procedural style, even though I personally recommend moving over to the OOP style. For more info, id recommend the PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$query  = "UPDATE billdata SET Total='$total', Due='$due' WHERE InvoiceNo=$invoiceno";
```

There should be a comma between the sets of values.
It is not a good idea to use the value from `$_POST()` as they are, better perform some validation checks.

Comment: $query  = "UPDATE billdata SET Total='$total', Due='$due' WHERE InvoiceNo='$invoiceno";'
this should be and it works Thanks for your support